Next.js does not treeshake properly
I have a /components directory in my project where it has an aggregator file (index.js) which re-exports all available components.

- src
  - app
  - components
    - agGrid
    - map
    - ...
    - index.js

I have a Map component which is imported/exported from this index.js but it's never been used through other components and my pages. As you can see below it's also in gray color with no usage!

I'm using leaflet for my Map component and I'm wondering why leaflet is in the final build of the project?

I also noticed that the MUI components that I've never used is also there!
What I tried and found out
When I remove/comment this import/export from index.js, it wouldn't be included in the final build! I expect that Next.js search through my project and if it doesn't find any usage, simply ignore it from the final bundle, but seems it doesn't have any plan for it!

When you use a barrel file (aggregator file), if it’s not configured for tree-shaking, importing it has the same cost as importing all the files individually. To address this, you should use optimizePackageImportsin your next.config file.
Example:
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    optimizePackageImports: ["@ui/components"],
  },
};

With that NextJS optimize your folder and barrel to map individual exports.
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/optimizePackageImports
It's more to optimize external packages but works with internal folder as well. I already use with my component folder.

Thanks for the response. Would you please tell me how to address my component directory here? Currently I'm using import aliases with jsconfig.json, and with that, I didn't get that right.

Sure! If you already have an alias for your components folder like @components, you can use the alias inside your next.config.js file to enable tree-shaking. In your next.config.js file, add something like this:
experimental: {optimizePackageImports: ["@components"]},
This will work depending on your NextJS version.
